# Laravel Livewire sharing data

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have one larvale blade with bellow div and text box

```
<td class="border px-4 py-2" x-data="{dropdown: false,nSValue:{{ $item->price}}, idValue: {{$item->id}}}" @click.away="dropdown = false">

<input x-model="nSValue" type="number" placeholder="0">

</td>
```

As you have in td I have 3 values in x-data

```
1. dropdown=false
2. nSValue which is price
3. idValue which is value
```

also now I am showing that

> nSValue

in text box

how can I get values of dropdown & nSValue & idValue in contoller?
I try getting values like **$nSValue** its not working

Answer (score 0):

There a few ways of doing this. Why do you need those values in the x-data if you are not using them in Alpine?

If this is a traditional form submit you could just do:

```
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{ $item->price }}" />
```

if you really want to fully use Alpine you could do something like

```html
<td class="border px-4 py-2" x-data="{
  dropdown: false,
  nSValue:{{ $item->price}}, 
  idValue: {{$item->id}},
  submit() {
    fetch('endpoint', {
      method: 'POST'
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.data),
    }
  }
}" @click.away="dropdown = false">

  <input x-model="nSValue" x-on:change="submit" type="number" placeholder="0">

</td>
```